# How can I change default image folder for timymce ajax file manager

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce

How can I specify default browse folder/path for file manager in TinyMCE ?

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Have you googled `How can I specify default browse folder/path for file manager in TinyMCE ?` There are some results that look good to me?

Comment: @relentless So users don't have to search for images used in email template. They will have all just after open file manager.

Comment: @Pekka I don't want to change config file. Maybe there is some propertie I can change.